# How to config window display in DockMenu

Tags: macos, appkit

I found some window will display in DockMenu and something not.
How can I config with AppKit?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do these apps use AppKit?

Comment: I develop a app use AppKit，some window can display here, some not...

Answer (score 1):

The window list in the Dock menu appears to be a copy of the window list in the Window menu. Setting property `excludedFromWindowsMenu` of the window to `NO`/`false` will remove the window from the Window menu and the Dock menu.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved config this
must need title bar
if u want to hide title bar use this code

```
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:)])
        [self setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleVisibility:)])
        [self setTitleVisibility:1];
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Read the question again.